# Contenteditable text selection with no outline

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

I have a `contenteditable` text structure like so:

```
<div class="content" contenteditable="true">
  <span contenteditable="false">
    <span class="chunk" contenteditable="true">This sentence contains </span>
  </span>
  <span contenteditable="false">
    <span class="chunk bold" contenteditable="true">some bold</span>
  </span>
  <span contenteditable="false">
    <span class="chunk" contenteditable="true">text!</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

This enables selecting text across all 3 "chunk" spans.  However, removing the "outline" from it using css *disables* selecting text:

```
.chunk {
  outline: 0px solid transparent;
}
```

Can anybody explain why?  [JSBIN example](http://jsbin.com/bosukakiyawo/1/edit?html,css,output)

**EDIT**

It's definitely the EXISTENCE of the outline that's causing the issue.  Giving it a `1px solid transparent` outline still allows text selection.  As soon as you specify `0px`, it prevents selection.